# Azure Data Studio not respect specified casing with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, azure-data-studio, quoted-identifier

Using Azure Data Studio with PostgreSQL Extension, the soft change the case of query, that leads to error.

Here is my Query :

```
SELECT * FROM workspaces
JOIN member on workspaces.id = member.workspaceId
```

Here is the error:

```
column member.workspaceid does not exist
```

Of course member.workspaceid does not exist, but member.workspaceId does.. How can I deal with it ? I tried to change Identifier Cas and Keyword Case in the PGSQL Extension to uppercase, lowercase and none, but still same message.

Comment: You created the table with double quotes around the columns. That makes them case sensitive. [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) `"workspaceId"` is a different name than `workspaceId`

Comment: @Thanks you for the referenced topic that works well ! just replace member.workspaceId by member."workspaceId"